# HttpURLConnection reading response content on 403 error

Tags: java, http, http-status-code-403

When I fetch data from an URL with a 403 response

```
is = conn.getInputStream();
```

It throws an IOException and I can't get the response data.

But when I use firefox and access that url directly, The ResponseCode is still 403, but I can get the html content

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The [`HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream()) method will return an [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) which can be used to retrieve data from error conditions (such as a 404), according to the javadocs.

Comment: No, it won't, for the code of the function contains only 'return null;' line. (Java 6,7)

Comment: @Gangnus Read the Javadoc carefully: "If the connection was not connected, or if the server did not have an error while connecting or if the server had an error but no error data was sent, this method will return null. This is the default."
Otherwise (errors 4xx), you will get the stream to read from.

Comment: @MiljenMikic The difference between code and Javadoc means only that the last one is erroneous.

Comment: @Gangnus HttpURLConnection is *abstract* class. Concrete implementation works exactly as explained in Javadoc.

Comment: @MiljenMikic It is abstract. But this function already IS there as I say.  There is no "missing implement exception". And concrete implementation works as you write it. You CAN override the parent's function, but you needn't. The Javadoc is erroneous and helps to make more errors.

Answer (score 23):

Usage example of `HttpURLConnection` :

```
String response = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://google.com/pagedoesnotexist");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Hack to force HttpURLConnection to run the request
    // Otherwise getErrorStream always returns null
    connection.getResponseCode();
    InputStream stream = connection.getErrorStream();
    if (stream == null) {
        stream = connection.getInputStream();
    }
    // This is a try with resources, Java 7+ only
    // If you use Java 6 or less, use a finally block instead
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream)) {
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        response = scanner.next();
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // Replace this with your exception handling
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Replace this with your exception handling
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I thought it had to be `(code >= 200) && (code < 300)`

Comment: @slf You're right. It actually depends on the implementation and the only "official" way is to check if `getErrorStream` returns null, but that only works after forcing the request to be executed. I update my code to reflect this.

Answer (score 15):

try something like this:

```
try {
    String text = "url";
    URL url = new URL(text);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    // fake request coming from browser
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String f = in.readLine();
    in.close();
    System.out.println(f);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getResponseCode() / 100 == 2 ? con.getInputStream() : con.getErrorStream()));
```

source
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30712213/505623

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error  even after adding agent string. Finally  after a days investigation figured out the issue. It is really weired if the url scheme start with "HTTPS" it results in error 403. It should be in lowercase ("https"). So make sure you call "url.toLowercase()" before opening the connection