# Strange status 403 after opening URLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I wonder why does this sample code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        testLink("http://google.com");
        testLink("http://stackoverflow.com");
        testLink("http://docs.oracle.com");
    }

    private static void testLink(String urlStr) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Usually prints:

```
200
403
200
```

and not:

```
200
200
200
```

Comment: Maybe the `User-Agent` the connection uses is not allowed by SO.

Comment: 403 error means forbidden permission denied.

Comment: I know what 403 means :-) The reason is the 'User-Agent'

Comment: Perhaps this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633048/httpurlconnection-reading-response-content-on-403-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403#Difference_from_status_.22401_Unauthorized.22), a 403 response generally indicates one of two conditions:

> Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not permitted to perform the requested operation.
>
> The operation is forbidden to all users. For example, requests for a directory listing return code 403 when directory listing has been disabled.

So most probably connecting to SO via that `User-Agent` is forbidden.

Comment: Apparently SO is not happy to get requests w/o user agent. Putting one makes it happy.