# How to read HTTP response in case of 400 error?

Tags: java, http

I am writing to an HTTP POST endpoint using code like this.

When the response code is 200 everything is OK.

When the response code is 400 though I cannot get `InputStream` and read the response.

I am just getting an exception on the line marked with  `/// error !!!`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: ... 
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at com.test123.Main009.main(Main009.java:41)
```

So is there a way to read the response body even though the response code is 4xx ?

```
package com.test123;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main009 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String username = "xxx";
        String password = "yyy";
        
        URL url = new URL("http://host/path");
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)uc;
        
        http.setRequestMethod("POST"); // PUT is another valid option
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        http.setDoInput(true);

        byte[] request = "{ id: \"test2\" }".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        int length = request.length;

        http.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(length);
        
        String userpass = username + ":" + password;
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        
        http.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        // http.connect();
        
        try(OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(request);
            os.flush();
            
            InputStream in = http.getInputStream(); /// error !!!  
            System.out.println(in);
        }
        

        
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the concrete error in this case?

Comment: There is nothing inherent about a 4xx status code that makes you unable to read the body. Any reason you haven't actually shown us the error? It seems important in this case.

Comment: I forgot ... Added the error now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8329674/759049

Answer (score 1):

In case of non-successful response codes, you have to read the body with [HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29).